# Momentary switch with IR receiver and transmitter

Tags: timer, 555

I want to make a momentary switch with help of IR receiver and transmitter. I need only a pulse near about 2 seconds and I chose this circuit

http://www.meedtech.com/touch-free-timer-switch-circuit/

But there is a problem with this circuit when I turn on the power supply. Initially the output goes to high even I though didn't turn on the transmitter circuit. Iindly help me out I don't want output on supply on.

Comment: That circuit is bogus.  What, exactly, do you want to do?

Comment: i need to on a relay only for 2 sec with a push button through IR remote

Comment: simply i have a motor and i want to control DOL of this this motor through IR remote

Comment: OK: 1. Do you want it to work so the motor runs for two  seconds no matter for how long or short a time you press the remote?  2. Assuming you've actually built this thing, does its output come on high on power-up and stay high, or is it momentary? 3. What happens when you shine the remote on the receiver?  4. Did you build it exacly like the schematic with all the parts specified?  5. What are the motor's specifications?  (Volts, Amps, AC, DC...)

Comment: 1. i need just a output pulse when remote button pressed not for long just pressed and next circuit of motor i already design that's some interlocking. 2. no output still low when we turn on the circuit supply just on by pressing remote button. 3. when remote button press in front of receiver just a 5 volt or 12 volt relay on and gives me a pulse. 4. yes i want schematic and part detail. 5. 24 volt motor DC 10 to 15 A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit shown below will start with the output low on power-up.

The output will go high for about 2 seconds when the remote is pressed.

The output can source about 4.5 volts and 100 milliamperes when it's high, so if you need more than that you can add whatever circuitry you need to get you where you want to be.

[image]